# self.navigationController always returns nil using storyboard to storyboard navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

**Problem :** I am trying to get the handle to navigation controller in my viewcontroller but it always returns nil, below is my code

Hierarchy : AppDelegate -> MainStoryboard -> nav Drawer -> TestingStoryboard -> testing

From Navigation Drawer i open the viewControl as below :

```
self.openNewStoryBoard(storyBoard: "testingone", scene: "initial")
func openNewStoryBoard(storyBoard:String, scene:String){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoard, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: scene) as UIViewController
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I have a navigationcontroller in my "testingone" storyboard which connects to a viewContorller "initial" via a relationship - "root view controller " to "viewController", connected this to testtingone class

In the code(testingOne) class i am trying to get the handle to navigationcontroller as below :

```
self.rootNav = self.navigationController!
```

But it always ends up nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By directly presenting your view controller, you're bypassing the navigation controller all together. Thats why you're getting `nil` when calling `self.navigationController`. You should present your navigation controller instead.

To do that, in your story board simply set the Storyboard ID of the navigation controller to `initial` instead of the view controller.